# How to handle many daily emails from cron efficiently?

Tags: email, cron, automation, parsing

With each new server comes at least one more daily crontab email. The FreeBSD servers even send two: a daily and a security run output. Thanks to my obsession with virtualisation the number of emails I need to read (and then often discard without further action) is becoming too much.

What ways are there to manage / automate this process? Can emails be replaced by something that is web based? Surely some of you must have found creative ways for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The emails are really for folks who are a small shop with a few boxes, and do not any monitoring infrastructure in place.   I would suggest looking into monitoring packages that will provide you the same insight, but from a more dashboard/alert me only if it's broken perspective.

Nagios (http://www.nagios.org) and Ganglia (http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) are both open source monitoring packages that can provide this type of functionality.